# How to access the invocation property?

Tags: mule, mule-el, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I am trying to access the _clienName from the invocation properties. I tried the below one, but doesnt help. any thoughts ? Is it really possible to access invocation property in a mule flow ?

> `#[message.invocationProperties['_clientName']]`

```
Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    __httpEvent=HttpEvent #188...9{apiName=.....95574017,something=99034}
    _clientId=680.....81d97344
    _clientName=abcd-app
  INBOUND scoped properties:
```

Comment: Invocation is nothing but flowVariable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invocation Properties can be accessed via flowVars: #[flowVars['_clientName']] or #[flowVars._clientName]

Answer (score 1):

Post Mule EE 3.4 there has been a naming change on all the invocation property as FlowVariables . Even now the invocation properties will work if you try using #[flowVars.name] . In the Message properties transformer you have option to set only as invocation properties but it can be accessed as flowVars in rest of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

In mule invocation scoped properties are nothing but flowVars. So you can access them by using the following mule expression

`#[flowVars.'_clientName']`

in the above expression no need to wrap the _clientName in square brackets, just quote them as I did.

FYI

Session scoped properties are nothing but sessionVars. So you can access them by using `#[sessionVars.'_clientName']`.

Though you have not asked about session scoped properties, I have answered it because by reading your question I came to know that you are asking the question by seeing the logs in the console caused by the `Logger` Component of `Mule`.

The logger, not only logs Invocation scoped properties but also session scoped properties as well. So I guess you might get a question in your mind about what are Session scoped properties, so answered it.